# Facebook Graph user id url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, userid

I'm using the Facebook Graph API to get the feeds of serveral political persons from Graph API.

In order to get the user id I can user this lookup-id.com which returns : '100002944537013' for my account: mingze.ni.

With this id, the Graph API returns nothing, means that it's actually not my real Facebook ID because the Feeds are null: 100002944537013/feed

Notice that the Facebook pages can have several formats:
.../my_page_name
.../pages/my_page_name
.../my_page_ID

And I've customized mine as firstname.lastname.

If I use '/me' in Graph, I can get my real Facebook ID which is '756641117777366' and my Feeds are correctly appeared.

So what's the difference of the real id '756641117777366' and what the ID '100002944537013' don't have any feed printed?

So do you have any ideas how to get the real Facebook ID using Graph? For ex:
.../profile.php?id=100011475758037

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `/me`, you don´t get the "real" ID, you only get an "App Scoped ID". But that´s all you need anyway. There is no way to get the real ID of a User Profile anymore, those third party apps usually scrape the profile, which is not allowed on Facebook. Pages on the other hand are different, you can use the real ID to get their feed.

Make sure you understand the difference between a User Profile and a Page. It is not possible to get any data of a User Profile without authorizing that specific user with the appropriate permissions - for example, you need to authorize the user with `user_posts` to get access to his posts.

Comment: Any ideas on getting the feed in Graph for the url like .../profile.php?id=100011475758037

Comment: you get the feed of a page with page-id/feed and the feed of a user with /me/feed or /me/posts. you can NOT get the feed of ANY user if that user did not authorize your app.